# Currently learning angular. Cannot use input as an argument because it has the optional marker?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a button component that takes an `id` parameter passed down by its parent component. In `this.crudService.DeletePost(this.id).subscribe( data => console.log(data))`, why am I getting an error of

> Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
> [1]   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CrudService } from 'src/app/service/crud.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-kehbab-menu',
  templateUrl: './kehbab-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./kehbab-menu.component.css']
})
export class KehbabMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() id?: string;

  constructor(private router: Router, private crudService: CrudService) { }

  ngOnInit( ): void {
  }

  async removePost() {

    //delete -- this is where I get the error saying this.id is undefined but I can console log it and it shows the id.
    await this.crudService.DeletePost(this.id).subscribe( data => console.log(data));

    //refresh home
    await this.router.navigateByUrl('/search', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
     }); 
  }

}
```

Comment: From where are you calling `removePost` method? check if calling HTML element has `id` or not, if no id exist then it will show `undefined` error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why am I getting an error of "Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

You are simply being warned of a potential problem in your code. You have defined `@Input() id?: string;`. This means that `id` is either a `string` or `undefined`. You then pass this variable to `this.crudService.DeletePost(this.id)` which I believe accepts a `string`. You are therefore trying to assign `string | undefined` to string.

To solve this you have a number of ways, a simple one is simply a check using `if`

```js
  async removePost() {
    if (this.id) {
          //delete -- this is where I get the error saying this.id is undefined but I can console log it and it shows the id.
    await this.crudService.DeletePost(this.id).subscribe( data => console.log(data));

    //refresh home
    await this.router.navigateByUrl('/search', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
     });
    } 
  }
```

You can also use non-null operator `this.crudService.DeletePost(this.id!)`. Note the `!`

Another option is typecasting `this.crudService.DeletePost(this.id as string)`

You can also just define your property as a string with a default value. You can then check if the property is `'0'` in the service

```
@Input() id = '0';
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works.